# What does "I have been out late the night before" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, phrase-meaning

What does

> I have been out late the night before

mean?

Does it mean that I come back home late?

Comment: It means you got your tenses mixed up.

Comment: What @HotLicks said.  The easiest fix is to change “have” to “had”.

Comment: @HotLicks Not necessarily so, it depends on the context. It would be quite permissible to say "I'm always slow in the morning when I have been out late the night before".

Comment: "to be out late" means that you were out later than usual in the evening. It normally refers to a situation where you go out for the evening and don't come home until later than usual, but could mean going out in the middle of the night for an errand/to the late-night shop/etc.